# Subscribe multiple methods in one line of code

Tags: c#, delegates

Given:

```
btn1.MouseDown += someMethod1;
btn1.MouseDown += someMethod2;
btn1.MouseDown += someMethod3;
```

How can I define a proper structure to allow this:

```
btn1.MouseDown += someMethods;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Delegate.Combine` to create a single delegate. Something like this (with different delegate types probably):

```
EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine((EventHandler)someMethod1,
                                                      (EventHandler)someMethod2,
                                                      (EventHandler)someMethod3);
SomeEvent += handler;
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegate.combine or just use '+' operator to chain multiple delegates.

```
btn1.MouseDown = new EventHandler(Method1) + new EventHandler(Method2) + new EventHandler(Method3) + ...;
```

Both are essentially the same.

Comment: Neat trick. It looks like if you just cast the first one as an EventHandler, the rest will auto-cast: `btn1.MouseDown += (EventHandler)someMethod1 + someMethod2 + someMethod3;`

Answer (score 1):

This might just be a trivial way of doing it, but you can do this:

```
EventHandler someMethods = someMethod1;

someMethods += someMethod2;
someMethods += someMethod3;

btn1.MouseDown += someMethods;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically the thing to do would be to have a collection of methods, and iterate over them:

```
foreach (var f in new EventHandler[]{someMethod1, someMethod2, someMethod3})
{
    btn1.MouseDown += f;
}
```

This could be turned into a single line using `List.ForAll()` if you want to use that instead of a `foreach`.